# Kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, apache-zookeeper, filebeat

I'm trying to wrap up changes to our Kafka but I'm in over my head and am having a hard time debugging the issue.

I have multiple servers funneling their Ruby on Rails logs to 1 Kafka broker using Filebeat, from there the logs go to our Logstash server, and are then stashed in Elasticsearch. I didnt setup the original system but I tried taking us down from 3 Kafka servers to 1 as they weren't need. I updated the IP address configs in these files in our setup to remove the 2 old Kafka servers and restarted the appropriate services.

```
# main (filebeat)
sudo vi /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
sudo service filebeat restart


# kafka
sudo vi /etc/hosts
sudo vi /etc/kafka/config/server.properties
sudo vi /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
sudo vi /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
sudo service kafka-server restart
sudo service zookeeper-server restart
sudo service filebeat restart


# elasticsearch
sudo service elasticsearch restart


# logstash
sudo vi /etc/logstash/conf.d/00-input-kafka.conf
sudo service logstash restart
sudo service kibana restart
```

When I tail the Filebeat logs I see this -

```
2018-04-23T15:20:05Z WARN kafka message: client/metadata got error from broker while fetching metadata:%!(EXTRA *net.OpError=dial tcp 172.16.137.132:9092: getsockopt: connection refused) 

2018-04-23T15:20:05Z WARN kafka message: client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to 

2018-04-23T15:20:05Z WARN client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers 

2018-04-23T15:20:05Z WARN kafka message: Closing Client 

2018-04-23T15:20:05Z ERR Kafka connect fails with: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
```

Answer (score 1):

> to 1 Kafka broker... I tried taking us down from 3 Kafka servers to 1 as they weren't need. I updated the IP address configs in these files in our setup to remove the 2 old Kafka servers and restarted the appropriate services

I think you are misunderstanding that Kafka is only a highly available system if you have more than one broker, so the other 2 **are needed** despite you possibly only providing a single broker in the logstash config

Your errors state the single broker refused a connection, and therefore no logs will be sent to it.

At a minimum, I would recommend 4 brokers, and a replication factor of 3 on all your critical topics for a useful Kafka cluster.. That way, you can tolerate broker outages as well as distribute the load of your Kafka brokers.

It would also be beneficial to make the topic count a factor of your total logging servers, as well as key a Kafka message based on the application type, for example. That way you are guaranteed log order for those applications

Comment: I bumped our number of brokers back up to 3 and restarted the kafka server on each of them. Now I'm receiving a `WARN kafka message: client/metadata found some partitions to be leaderless` error when tailing filebeat.

Comment: It's just a warning. I think this is expected behavior. Meaning that you have unassigned partitions since you added brokers